# PLAID connection to Wise app, safety after the fact

Tags: privacy, account-security

PLAID is used by Wise app and I disconnected from the connected bank after the set up which was less than 24 hrs ago, changed password, then emailed PLAID and Wise to delete my personal information.  Is my personal info safe? What happens if PLAID’s data gets breached? I haven’t heard yet, but now I am regretting it.  The Wise app set up required images of my ID, ss#, and photo of my face. - please help!

Comment: Welcome to the community. Since Wise is a financial company, I would be guessing they have to comply with legal constraints which would mean they would still have to store your data for a certain period of time till deletion... Did you read their terms and conditions and their data privacy rules?...